# How to change labels and radiobuttons after a button clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have programmed a script which takes random four elements from a table and question to the user using `tkinter`, `random` and `sqlite3`. Currently, I can ask a question. Implement four choices with `radiobuttons`. I can also test if the answer is correct or not and show the result to the user via `toplevel()`.

Problem is, how can I refresh the question after the continue button clicked?

My whole code is below. I have tried refreshing the random numbers and labels under `continue_asking` or another `def` called from `continue_asking`. But it doesn't work at all.

```
from tkinter import *
from sqlite3 import *
from random import *


class Question(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.prepare_question()

    def prepare_question(self):
        self.tumu = {0:['ask1','answer1'], # instead of SQL query
                     1:['ask2','answer2'],
                     2:['ask3','answer3'], 
                     3:['ask4','answer4']}
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.choiceFrame = Frame(self)
        self.choiceFrame.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.choiceNum = IntVar()
        for i in range(4):
            Radiobutton(self.choiceFrame, text=self.tumu[i][1], variable=self.choiceNum, value=i) \
                        .grid(row=2, column=i, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.q_num = randrange(4)
        self.q_word = self.tumu[self.q_num][0]

        lbl_question = Label(self, text="Which one is the meaning of the word: " + self.q_word, font="Courier 12")
        lbl_question.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

        txt_question = Text(self, height=1, font="Courier 12", pady=2)
        txt_question.tag_configure("myStyle", font="Courier 12 bold")
        txt_question.insert("end", "Please choose the answer and ")
        txt_question.insert("end", "click okay to see the results.", "myStyle")
        txt_question.configure(state="disabled")
        txt_question.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, sticky=W)

        btn_okay = Button(self, text="Okay", font="12", command=self.a_control)
        btn_okay.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def a_control(self):
        self.choosenWord = self.q_num
        self.frm_answer = Toplevel()
        self.frm_answer.title("Result")
        self.selectedWord = self.choiceNum.get()
        txt_result = Text(self.frm_answer, height=4, width = 40)

        if self.choosenWord == self.selectedWord:
            txt_result.insert("end", "Congrats! Your answer is correct.\n")
        else:
            txt_result.insert("end","Your answer is not correct.\n")
            txt_result.insert("end", "Correct answer is " + self.tumu[self.q_num][1] + '\n')

        txt_result.insert("end", "Please click Continue to continue.\n")
        txt_result.insert("end", "Click cancel to quit.")
        txt_result.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx = 5, pady=5)
        txt_result.configure(state="disabled")
        btn_continue = Button(self.frm_answer, text="Continue", command=lambda: self.continue_asking(self.frm_answer))
        btn_continue.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky = W)

        btn_quit = Button(self.frm_answer, text="Cancel", command=self.end_asking)
        btn_quit.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky = W)

    def continue_asking(self,frm_answer):
        frm_answer.destroy()

    def end_asking(self):
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
app = Question(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried adding prepare_question to continue_asking. It keeps asking questions but widgets are not changing. They are just overlapping.[image]

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Does it reset them to the wrong value? Does it reset the wrong widgets?

Comment: @BryanOakley they are overlapping with the solution in the answer. At mine, it was throwing error or nothing.

Comment: @alisrn i review my mistakes, please check if everything is fine now, let me know if it's still buggy !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

So let's restart from scratch, i was totally wrong because no widget was removed and they stacked in the main Frame children list.

You still don't need to write so much code, mostly move some parts.

First, to be able to update the widgets and prepare the new question peacefully, move 
`self.create_widgets()` in the constructor and put the random index  `self.q_num` and `self.q_word` inside `prepare_question`, since it belongs to the logic of the question creation.

In `create_widgets()` you only need to keep some control on the label question, so we add `self.lbl_question`...

Finally, i suggest to create a new function `update_widgets()`, but you can put the logic inside `continue_asking()`.

In this function, call `prepare_question` to update the next question (sql query and random stuff). Since we move the random index, everything is ready to update each widget:

- text of the question label
- text of radiobuttons. I'm not so proud of the loop to change those, but that'll do the trick. (we keep the values created for the indexes to match the new ones, i'm not very sure about this logic with SQL queries, i follow your first implementation with `text=self.tumu[i][1]`)

*If someone can tell how to get the radiobutton value more easily, i'm interested*

Here is the whole code:

```
from tkinter import *
from sqlite3 import *
from random import *


class Question(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.prepare_question()
        self.create_widgets()

    def prepare_question(self):
        self.tumu = {0:['ask1','answer1'], # instead of SQL query
                     1:['ask2','answer2'],
                     2:['ask3','answer3'], 
                     3:['ask4','answer4']}

        self.q_num = randrange(4)
        self.q_word = self.tumu[self.q_num][0]

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.choiceFrame = Frame(self)
        self.choiceFrame.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.choiceNum = IntVar()
        for i in range(4):
            Radiobutton(self.choiceFrame, text=self.tumu[i][1], variable=self.choiceNum, value=i) \
                        .grid(row=2, column=i, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.lbl_question = Label(self, text="Which one is the meaning of the word: " + self.q_word, font="Courier 12")
        self.lbl_question.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

        txt_question = Text(self, height=1, font="Courier 12", pady=2)
        txt_question.tag_configure("myStyle", font="Courier 12 bold")
        txt_question.insert("end", "Please choose the answer and ")
        txt_question.insert("end", "click okay to see the results.", "myStyle")
        txt_question.configure(state="disabled")
        txt_question.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, sticky=W)

        btn_okay = Button(self, text="Okay", font="12", command=self.a_control)
        btn_okay.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def a_control(self):
        self.choosenWord = self.q_num
        self.frm_answer = Toplevel()
        self.frm_answer.title("Result")
        self.selectedWord = self.choiceNum.get()
        txt_result = Text(self.frm_answer, height=4, width = 40)

        if self.choosenWord == self.selectedWord:
            txt_result.insert("end", "Congrats! Your answer is correct.\n")
        else:
            txt_result.insert("end","Your answer is not correct.\n")
            txt_result.insert("end", "Correct answer is " + self.tumu[self.q_num][1] + '\n')

        txt_result.insert("end", "Please click Continue to continue.\n")
        txt_result.insert("end", "Click cancel to quit.")
        txt_result.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx = 5, pady=5)
        txt_result.configure(state="disabled")
        btn_continue = Button(self.frm_answer, text="Continue", command=self.continue_asking)
        btn_continue.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky = W)

        btn_quit = Button(self.frm_answer, text="Cancel", command=self.end_asking)
        btn_quit.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky = W)

    def continue_asking(self):
        self.frm_answer.destroy()
        self.update_widgets()

    def update_widgets(self):
        self.prepare_question()

        # change question text 
        self.lbl_question.configure(text = "Which one is the meaning of the word: " + self.q_word)

        # change Radiobutton
        for child in self.choiceFrame.children.values():
            index = child.config()['value'][4]                              
            child.configure(text = self.tumu[index][1])
            if index == 0: # reset the focus
                child.select()

    def end_asking(self):
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
app = Question(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

---

**First crap post:** (the not to do part)

You don't need to change so much code to fix the present issue, have you already tried the following ?

```
def continue_asking(self,frm_answer):
    frm_answer.destroy()
    self.prepare_question()
```

I won't review the whole code, there is another place for that, but you can also avoid the lambda when you call `continue_asking()`, since you store the frame in `self.frm_answer`

```
    btn_continue = Button(self.frm_answer, text="Continue", command=self.continue_asking)
    # [...]

def continue_asking(self):
    self.frm_answer.destroy()
    self.prepare_question()
```

Comment: It does work but, there create_widgets after prepare question. All the widgets crossing.

Comment: i don't have this side effect on a linux plateform, sorry about the wrong tip. But in this case you should split `create_widget` and/or  add a new function to alter only the text and the radiobuttons

Comment: @alisrn and what about changing `lbl_question` to `self.lbl_question` and the same for `txt_question` and the buttons ?

Comment: Nope. Editing my question and adding the result.

Comment: now i understand how my fix is wrong (the test datas i created too...) i thought the widgets were garbage collected when we create and assign the new ones, but all widgets stay as children inside the main Frame. i will edit all of this in a moment

Comment: Thank you for all your care. :) It works like a charm. And I have learnt from you. Thanks.